# How to prevent push notifications for active/watching channels in a Capacitor app using GetStream.io chat?

Tags: push-notification, capacitor, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I am using GetStream.io for implementing chat functionality in my Capacitor app. Currently, I am receiveing push notifications for all the new messages, even when I am actively watching the channel and chatting with the person.

I want to prevent receiving push notifications for the channels that are currently active and being watched by the user in my app. Is there a way to achieve this using the GetStream.io dashboard or by configuring the chat SDK?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

I have searched through the GetStream.io documentation, but couldn't find a solution to prevent receiving push notifications for the channel that the user is currently watching.

Desired Behavior:
The user should not receive push notifications for the active channel where they have it open and are actively engaged in a conversation, as this can be annoying and disruptive for the user experience.

Both Android and IOS same behaviour.